# Jupyter notebook does not print logs to the output cell

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am currently using `Jupyter` notebook and I would like to force it to print out `Python` logs to the output cell.

I am using old notebook that used to work this way, probably in older version of `Jupyter` notebook.

I have logging set as:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logging.root.level = 20
```

But when I then call:

```
logging.info("hello world")
```

It does not print anything in the output cell. It just prints out the stuff in the console in which I started the `Jupyter` notebook.

I am using `python 2.7.10` and installed packages in my virtual environment are:

```
appnope==0.1.0
backports-abc==0.4
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
certifi==2016.2.28
decorator==4.0.9
functools32==3.2.3.post2
gnureadline==6.3.3
ipykernel==4.3.1
ipython==4.1.2
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==4.1.1
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.2.2
jupyter-console==4.1.1
jupyter-core==4.1.0
MarkupSafe==0.23
mistune==0.7.2
nbconvert==4.1.0
nbformat==4.0.1
notebook==4.1.0
path.py==8.1.2
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.6
ptyprocess==0.5.1
Pygments==2.1.3
pyzmq==15.2.0
qtconsole==4.2.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
terminado==0.6
tornado==4.3
traitlets==4.1.0
wheel==0.24.0
```

Was logging printout in the cell changed? Is there some way how I can force `Jupyter` to write out logging to the output cell?

Comment: Works for me. I get a red box in the notebook with the info message. With version 4.0.1.

Comment: @MikeMüller version 4.0.1. of which package? ipython?

Comment: Yes, IPython and jupyter 1.0.0 on Python 3.5.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to install ipython 4.0.1 instead, but still the same problem.

Comment: Check what `sys.stderr` is. Should be `<ipykernel.iostream.OutStream at ....>`.

Comment: `sys.stderr` is in my case `<ipykernel.iostream.OutStream at 0x1079e9e10>` which seems to be correct.

Comment: Changes to logging configurations in Jupyter will probably require a Kernel Reset before taking effect.

Comment: In my case, even more strangely, the logger actually was working if I created a new Jupyter Notebook with the exact same configuration and with exactly the same logger and logging configurations as the one where it didn't work. However, I did need it to print in my old notebook. The only solution was to [manually configure a stream handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60102947/3873799).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one my old `python 2.7.10` virtualenv where `jupyter` works as desired.

```
appnope==0.1.0
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
boto==2.38.0
bz2file==0.98
certifi==2015.9.6.2
decorator==4.0.4
functools32==3.2.3.post2
gensim==0.12.2
gnureadline==6.3.3
httpretty==0.8.6
ipykernel==4.1.1
ipython==4.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==4.1.1
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.1.1
jupyter-console==4.0.3
jupyter-core==4.0.6
MarkupSafe==0.23
mistune==0.7.1
nbconvert==4.1.0
nbformat==4.0.1
notebook==4.0.6
numpy==1.10.1
path.py==8.1.2
Pattern==2.6
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.5
ptyprocess==0.5
Pygments==2.0.2
pyzmq==14.7.0
qtconsole==4.1.0
requests==2.8.1
scipy==0.16.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
smart-open==1.3.0
terminado==0.5
tornado==4.2.1
traitlets==4.0.0
wheel==0.24.0
```

Some packages are not related with the `jupyter` problem here, problem will probably be in versions of some relevant packages. I'll try further investigate exactly where.

**EDIT:**

At the end I have found that the problem is in the package: `ipykernel==4.3.1` or since `ipykernel==4.3.0` everything works fine with `ipykernel==4.1.1` or `ipykernel==4.2.2`.

Issue was reported at github to the jupyter and ipykernel: https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/111

Answer (score 13):

The earlier answers seem no longer to work.  The most complete one no longer works because there are no default handlers, so modifying the zeroeth doesn't work.  Also, messing with the root logger seems potentially fraught when running in a notebook.

In order to get the `"foo"` logger to put its output in the cell you can do the following:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))
```

So add the handler yourself, and direct its output.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only solution that worked for me. In my case, even more strangely, the logger _actually was working_ if I created a new Jupyter Notebook _with the exact same configuration_ and with _exactly the same logger and logging configurations_ as the one where it didn't work. However, I did need it to print in my old notebook.

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully the jupyter folks will fix this. However, I found a workaround you can use for now. It seems that maybe the new versions of jupyter notebook do not show stderr in the notebook, but send stderr to the terminal instead. But, they still print stdout. You can set the handler of the root logger to stdout:

```
import logging
import sys

# Get root logger (all other loggers will be derived from this logger's
# properties)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.warning("I will output to terminal")  # No output in notebook, goes to terminal

# assuming only a single handler has been setup (seems 
# to be default in notebook), set that handler to go to stdout.
logger.handlers[0].stream = sys.stdout

logger.warning("FOO")  # Prints: WARNING:root:FOO

# Other loggers derive from the root logger, so you can also do:
logger2 = logging.getLogger("logger2")
logger2.warning("BAR")  # Prints: WARNING:logger2:BAR
```

If you put this at the top of your notebook, this change should propagate to any loggers initialized in modules you import as well, since generally loggers will inherit the setup of the root logger.

Comment: The above does not work for me (python 3.6.8). My logger has *no* handlers attached to it, so trying to set the stream of the zeroeth just gets me an array reference error.

Comment: And now it doesn't save to a file

Answer (score 3):

None of the workarounds suggested here worked for me for me, but the below did, maybe it will help somebody else.

Using python 3.4.3, jupyter-client==4.1.1, jupyter-core==4.0.6

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info("hello")
```

> INFO:**main**:hello

Answer (score 0):

The solution to specify the stream works well. Another option for configuration if using the dictConfig is to add the stream as a parameter

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig({
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": "{levelname} {asctime} | {message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "default",
            "stream": sys.stdout,
        }
    },
    "root": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "handlers": ["console"],
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it suffices to set the `stream` parameter in `logging.basicConfig`:

```
import logger
import sys
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    format="(%asctime)s | %(message)s", 
    stream=sys.stdout
)
```

Afterwards, the basic logging output is correctly directed to below the cell.