# Jupyter notebook logging [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook

I'm observing a strange behavior in my current `jupyter notebook` setup: upon each warning or error reported I'm getting the whole stackdump of Broken Pipe error in addition to the main error message being displayed.

[image: as in here]

This gets extremely disturbing when one cell generates a bunch of non-critical errors and the browser window hangs up just trying to render all of the accompanying stacktraces. Any idea in which direction should I investigate to nail this down?
I've already tried to redirect `logger.handlers[0]` to `stdout` and `stderr` as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936086/jupyter-notebook-does-not-print-logs-to-the-output-cell), but with no effect (regular logger messages as in `logger.debug()` and `print()` are processed correctly).

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.handlers[0].stream = sys.stderr
```

I'm using `ipykernel 4.3.1` (Python3)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue.